# How to detect and handle 404 error with Sammy.Template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-code-404, sammy.js

I load a template taking the template name from a route with Sammy.js, but if the file is not found, I want to redirect the user to another page. Basically, I have:

```
this.use(Sammy.Template, 'tpl');

this.get('#/:page', function() {

    // render a template
    // this.load()

    this.render('templates/' + this.params['page'] + '.tpl').swap();
});
```

How can I handle the 404 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can use load with passing options, I would do (of the top of my head. There might be syntax errors but the logic is there):

```
this.load('templates/' + this.params['page'] + '.tpl', {error: function(response) { ... handle error }).interpolate(null, location).swap();
```

Do the 404 check in the error function.